# Custom Filter in Liferay Portal 7.2

Tags: search, filter, liferay, liferay-7.2

I have to build one functionality for the filter of Liferay documents and media.
I have to filter out a search on the basis of the extension of the file. For example, we have a set of .pdf,.xml,.txt or image file. Then when the user selects PDF it should display only PDF files. Same For image or text file.
Same as Ecommerce site filter.

Comment: Stll exists a search facet for document type.. no?

Comment: No, there is some facet like search facet,custom facet, and typefacet.But i actually wanted to implement using custom code. Please Help if anybody has a solution.

Comment: hm 7.2  ... ? new search api or old ?

Comment: in 7.2 with the new api that's the link you want to read .. https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-2/frameworks/-/knowledge_base/f/building-search-queries-and-filters

Answer (score 1):

You can directly query the search engine (Elasticsearch) using the following code.
You have to add your conditions to the booleanQuery variable using BooleanQuery, TermQuery, TermRangeQuery, MultiMatchQuery, etc..

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQueryImpl();
TermQueryImpl termQuery = new TermQueryImpl(new QueryTermImpl(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_NAME, DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.class.getName()));
booleanQuery.add(termQuery, BooleanClauseOccur.MUST);

SearchContext searchContext = new SearchContext();
searchContext.setCompanyId(companyId);
searchContext.setGroupIds(new long[]{groupId});
Hits hits = IndexSearcherHelperUtil.search(searchContext, booleanQuery);
```

Then you can cast your search result hits to Asset Entries by using _assetHelper.getAssetEntries(hits) where _assetHelper is a reference to AssetHelper class defined in this way:

```
@Reference
private AssetHelper _assetHelper;
```

Hope it helps!